# Putting JSON data to DataTables

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax, json, datatables

I'm trying to insert all the json data into a dataTable after a success response from ajax call. I'm sure that I'm fetching all the json data but I don't know what to put in the parameter in value. Help me. my ajax code. The problem here is I want to put all the array in  the table.

```
function getData(){

$.ajax({
  url: "<?php echo site_url('getcontributiontable'); ?>",
  type: 'GET',
  data: 'getContributionTable',
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {
    var otable = $("#dataTable").dataTable();
    otable.fnClearTable();

    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
      var i = this.length; // this is to check if the loop is getting the right count of array in the object.
      alert(i);

      otable.dataTable().fnAddData([
        value[0].ref_no,       // for this line of code it only gets the first row or first array in the object. 
        value[0].table_name,
        value[0].agency,
        value[0].year,
        value[0].date_added
      ]);

    });
```

[image]

Comment: How does your JSON looks like?

Comment: you can refer to the image above. in firebug console..

Comment: Yes, by `ctrl`-`+`'ing a lot of times, I was able to see the structure :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 value[0].ref_no,       
 value[0].table_name,
 value[0].agency,
 value[0].year,
 value[0].date_added
```

To

```
  value[key].ref_no,       
  value[key].table_name,
  value[key].agency,
  value[key].year,
  value[key].date_added
```

Comment: I've tried your suggestion before it doesn't make any changes. :(

Answer (score 0):

here's the code:

```js
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
              
                var t = this.length;

                  for(var k=0; k<t; k++){
                    
                   otable.dataTable().fnAddData([

                   value[k].ref_no,
                   value[k].from_range,
                   value[k].to_range,
                   value[k].monthly_salary,
                   value[k].cont_er,
                   value[k].cont_ee,
                   value[k].cont_total
  
                   ]);

                      }
                         
               });
```

I've got this answer from a friend. Thanks for all of your responses :D

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are passing first object from the received JSON (value[0]).In datatables you don't need to use a loop if you have your JSON in a particular format which you need. Looking at your JSON, below is what I would have done in the success call:

```
 success: function(data) {
       var myData = data;
       var otable = $("#dataTable").dataTable({
          "destroy" : true,           //destroys any current datable with the same name and creates a new one with new options
          "data"    : "myData",
          "columns" : [
            {"data" : "ref_no"},
            {"data" : "table_name"},
            {"data" : "agency"},
            {"data" : "year"},
            {"data" : "date_added"},
         ]
    });
 }
```

Hope this works!!